# `! source ll_env/bin/activate` fails to activate the environment

Tags: python

The environment can be activated from the command line:

```
me at me in ~/desktop/django/learning_log on master [!?]
$ source ll_env/bin/activate
(ll_env) 
me at me in ~/desktop/django/learning_log on master [!?]
$ django-admin version
1.11.13
```

But within the interactive mode of Ipythonself.

```
In [18]: ! source ll_env/bin/activate

In [19]: ! django-admin version
2.0.5

It indicates that the environment was not activated at all.
```

What's happening behind command `! source ll_env/bin/activate`

Comment: It actually works but the shell where `!` command runs is immediately discarded after executing command.

Comment: very clear and short answer, could you please transmit it to answer. @Sraw

Comment: For helping others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually works but the shell where `!` command runs is immediately discarded after executing command.

Answer (score 1):

When you run !command a shell will open, run the command and then exit. Your env activate in shell but shell will exit after execute the command. You can do ! source ll_env/bin/activate & django-admin version.